# Disable Auto Login after registration in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

Please can someone help me. How do I disable auto login after registration in laravel 5.3.
I can do it in 5.2, but not in 5.3.

Comment: Do you just want them to be redirected to the login page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `5.3` you just need to override the register method. You can add the following to your `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController`:

```
/**
 * Handle a registration request for the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    //The auto login code has been removed from here.

    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Furthermore, you can either change the redirect path in the `register` method itself or just update the `$redirectTo` property towards the top of the class.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

There is no  AuthController.php  in Laravel 5.3.* so modify your RegisterController.php and add these lines

`use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;`

then, add this line to handle registration request for the above parameters

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));
    return $this->registered($request, $user)
        ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}

 $this->guard()->login($user);
```

Answer (score 1):

In 5.3 you need to override [`register()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php#L29) method in `RegisterController.php` which will be build after using `make:auth` command. Just comment `login()` part:

```
//$this->guard()->login($user);
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside **RegistersUsers** trait there is a function

```
protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
{
    if(!$user->active){
        // store msg in session and display to user
        Auth::logout();
    }
}
```

this is the function that executes as soon the user registers, here even you check check if user is verified and any other code and Auth::logout(), this is the best way to do it. No need to change any code elsewhere that can messup with framework.

Comment: where is this file `RegistersUsers` ?